# How can I check if an element has been removed from the DOM?

Tags: asp.net, selenium-rc, webdriver

I'm using Selenium WebDriver (WebDriver.dll) v2.19.0 and I need to verify that an element has been removed from the DOM.

**How can I verify that an element is no longer in the DOM?**

I have an `RemoteWebDriver` which I'm using to get a reference to a `div` which has a delete button in it. When this button is clicked, some JavaScript deletes the `div` and I need to confirm that the `div` is no longer in the DOM. The `div` is not unique within the DOM, the are many like to. Is there a way to query the web driver so see if that element is still present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what language you use (WebDriver.dll seems like c# or something?). But this works for every language I think. One solution could be that you call the `findElement()` method of WebDriver and try to get the div-element. If the div is no longer attached to the DOM you get an `ElementNotFoundException`. I know it is not a good design but it can be a solution in this situation: You could catch the exception and then you know that the div is no longer attached to the DOM (i know, the purpose of exceptions is not program logic like this).

Another solution can be that you query the source code with `getPageSource()` method. then you can parse the source yourself with XML-Parsers if your element is still attached to the DOM.